# Running an android application inside an existing application in a small window

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run an android application inside my application in small window. I have searched threads but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way for you to embed another application in your application in standard Android. A custom ROM could do this, though.

Comment: what if i had the source code ? is it possible to embed it on the go?

Comment: @FelixIzraital: Only by substantially rewriting it (e.g., replacing all activities with fragments or something).